Serverless-offline No matching handler found for 'src\functions\graphql/handler'
I was trying to run backend project that uses graphql, this is working in my colleagues macOs but not in my windows. What problem does it seem to be? This is the error i got when trying to run the project.
    Error message:

    serverless offline --host 0.0.0.0 --httpPort 3001 --useChildProcesses
    Environment: win32, node 18.17.0, framework 3.38.0 (local), plugin 7.2.3, SDK 4.5.1
    Docs:        docs.serverless.com
    Support:     forum.serverless.com
    Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

    Error:
        No matching handler found for 'src\functions\graphql/handler' in 'D:\Workspace\TimeBook-API-first-     release'. Check your service definition.

    2 deprecations found: run 'serverless doctor' for more details
    error Command failed with exit code 1.

here is the handler.ts
    import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-lambda";
    import { environment } from "@utils/index";
    import cache from "./cache";
    import context from "./context";
    import dataSources from "./dataSources";
    import { formatError } from "./error";
    import plugins from "./plugins";
    import schema from "./schema";

    const server = new ApolloServer({
     cache,
     context,
    dataSources,
    formatError,
    plugins,
    schema,
    debug: environment.isDev(),
    introspection: environment.isDev(),
  });

 export const main = server.createHandler();

Plase help whats wrong?

I  found the answer. It was because of wrong path as it should have been "/" but the path was determined as "" so I just replaced "" with "/" it.
